# How to configure iso8583 with WSO2 ESB tcp transporter

Tags: wso2, iso8583, wso2-esb

My requirement is to configure WSO2 esb to receive ISO8583 payload from tcp transporter and process data and send response in iso8583 message format using tcp .

Thank You

Comment: My problem is configuring custom tcp transporter which supports ISO 8583 message format when using wso2 esb .this question is clear for the people who has idea about ESB and transporters.plus i got the required answer for my question

Comment: This question is valid, hence revoke the on hold state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via writing your own class mediator or writer your own custom transport sender, listener, message formatter and builder.

In my past experience, I have seen financial institutes do the heavy modification on the message formats based on their custom requirement. Hence it is quite difficult to determine the generic format and elements of the messages most of the time.

You can find the sample for writing Transport sender and listener, message formatter and builder in [1].
[1]http://manoj-fernando.blogspot.com/2013/08/iso8583-with-wso2-esb.html

Comment: i refereed this sample in this example where do we have to put custom ISO8583TransportSender  .i have inserted this jav in to dropins directory but when i start the server it throws null pointer  exception  [2014-12-08 11:34:24,657] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Error occured while deploying bundles in the dropins directory
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.getNewBundleInfoLines(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:105)